# How to use find command with sorting by creation date&time recursively?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I have many time tried for this issue.
find command results do not care listing order.

How to use directory listing based on creation date&time from find recursive command result ?

```
ls -lc
```

This works good , but not recursively way .

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec ls -lc {} \;
```

This doesn’t work.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" | sort -n
```

This also only name based.

Comment: i have found  solution like below !! on macos
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
find . -type f -iname  "*.txt"  -exec stat -f '%B %m %N' {} \; | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev | sort -n
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 2):

solution from https://superuser.com/q/294161/992527 combined with the command from the question:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n
```

See the different answers for variations of the command.
Explanation cited from referenced question:

> `printf` arguments from [`man find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):
>
> - `%Tk`: File's last modification time in the format specified by `k`.
> - `@`: seconds since Jan. 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT, with fractional part.
> - `c`: locale's date and time (Sat Nov 04 12:02:33 EST 1989).
> - `%p`: File's name.

Solution for MacOS copied from @cooljobs' comment to the question

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec stat -f '%B %m %N' {} \; | rev | cut -d '/' -f 1 | rev | sort -n
```

Comment: @cooljobs : Doesn't need to. You specified in your Tags that you are searching for a solution for Linux, not MacOS.

Comment: Ohh, that is my mistake , sorry to you !  i forgot to add macos also  :-)